# SQL Auto-populate ID column based on another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, uniqueidentifier

I have a workflow where source table is used to populate the destination table.
I have tried to simulate this workflow in the code below.

```
-- creating/populating source table
CREATE TABLE #SourceTable
(
     CampaignName VARCHAR(50),
     CustomerNumber INT
)

INSERT INTO #SourceTable 
VALUES ('Campaign1', 1111), ('Campaign1', 2222), ('Campaign1', 3333),
       ('Campaign2', 4444), ('Campaign2', 2222), ('Campaign2', 1111)

-- create/populate destination table
CREATE TABLE #DestinationTable
(
    CampaignID INT,
    CampaignName VARCHAR(50),
    CustomerNumber INT
)

-- Simulating populating the #DestinationTable
INSERT INTO #DestinationTable (CampaignName, CustomerNumber)
    SELECT CampaignName, CustomerNumber
    FROM #SourceTable
```

The source table will get created in some way, but then it is used to populate the destination table in the same way as my sample code.

The destination table is at CustomerNumber level. I want to autopopulate an ID field (without the user having to code it in) that will give a new number at CampaignName level.

So for example, I want the output of the `#DestinationTable` to be:

```
CampaignID  CampaignName    CustomerNumber
------------------------------------------
1           Campaign1         1111
1           Campaign1         2222
1           Campaign1         3333
2           Campaign2         4444
2           Campaign2         2222
2           Campaign2         1111
```

But I need the `CampaignID` column to be auto-populated whenever new rows are being inserted, like an `IDENTITY` column, but instead of giving each row a number, I need it to give each `CampaignName` a new number.

Is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This one can be achieved using `dense_rank()`.

```
SELECT dense_rank() over (order by CampaignName) as rn, CampaignName, CustomerNumber
FROM #SourceTable
```

To validate if your `customer number` and `campaign` name already existed on your destination use `not exists` keyword.

```
SELECT dense_rank() over (order by t1.CampaignName) as rn, t1.CampaignName, t1.CustomerNumber
FROM #SourceTable t1
WHERE not exists (select 1 from #DestinationTable t2
    where t2.CustomerNumber = t1.CustomerNumber and t2.CampaignName = t1.CampaignName)
```

Comment: I have clarified the auto-populate requirement. I need it to populate without the user having to write the code. Similar to Identity field. 
Also, would you code work when new rows are being added to the table?

Comment: this query came from your source table, so if your sourcetable is empty, it wont generate rows.

Comment: Ok I see it now. 
The Destination table would have already had the CampaignID column populated. So how would your query know not to give the same IDs as already existing in the Destination table?
The Destination table is being appended on each insert, so the query needs to take into account the numbers that are already there.
I thought about a solution that adds a similar code to yours to a `INSTEAD OF` Trigger.

Comment: I think something like this would work. 
What I was really hoping for was a way to manipulate `IDENTITY` type field to `PARTITION BY` a particular column. Was hoping there was already something build in that could do that